# Edit in place with javascript and update the array value?

Tags: php, javascript

I am not using any javascript plugin,

```
<html>
<head>
<title>sample dynamic select list</title>
<script language='javascript'>
function changeContent(tablecell)
{
    tablecell.innerHTML = "<INPUT type=text name=newname onBlur=\"javascript:submitNewName(this);\" value=\""+tablecell.innerHTML+"\">";
    tablecell.firstChild.focus();
}
function submitNewName(textfield)
{

    textfield.parentNode.innerHTML= textfield.value;
}
</script>
</head>
<?php
$exrate = array("USD"=>array('sale'=>123,"buy"=>456))
?>
<body>
Double click on any cell. Then enter your own text and then tab out or click on other place.
<table border=1 bgcolor=gray>
<tr>
<th>Currency</th>
<th>Buy</th>
<th>Sale</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>USD</td>
<td onDblClick="javascript:changeContent(this);"><?=$exrate["USD"]["sale"]?></td>
<td onDblClick="javascript:changeContent(this);"><?=$exrate["USD"]["buy"]?></td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

When Double click on any cell Then enter your own text and then tab out or click on other place.so How can I update these data example store in an array ,can store values in every time edited?

Comment: i am not sure what you are trying to say but you create an array and push the value on every edit, `array.push(newvalue)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first persist these values server-side somehow (how is $exrate being stored? is it in the session, database, etc?) and then you could bind an even on the tablecell's blur event and make an ajax request to update the values in your server-side store.

That said, with so many easy to use and lightweight javascript frameworks/libraries out there I don't see why you would want to do this manually (except maybe as a learning exercise or an innovative form of self-flagelation).

Comment: yes,I just learning only.,if too many thing like you said I back to use js frameworks ...